Immediately create another conversation after one conversation end with python-telegram-bot
I'm trying to implement a telegram bot with the following flow:

User A sends a request to Bot by command
Bot saves the request to database, replies A that Bot has received the request and the request is pending to be approved by B
Bot sends a message to B with 2 buttons Accept and Reject
User B taps Accepts or Rejects
Bot saves B's option, replies B that Bot has saved his selection, then sends A that B has accepted/rejected the request

I'm using python-telegram-bot with ConversationHandler to handle command sent from A and step 2 is now done. But I'm stuck on spawning the second conversation with B properly. The first idea was using Bot to send a message, but I don't know how to handle B's reply then.
I can save chat_id of A and B to the database.
I want to receive advices on how to implement this flow. Or any example is also appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Basic setup is you have to use ,

CommandHandler
CallbackQueryHandler
UserID's

Based on "Accept" and "Reject" buttons from Command Handler save database and update users response on command , User Id use for multiple user sync in context , call back Query handler will help you to update a request status based on "Accept" and "Reject" from user and notifying the relevant user.
you can look into this when development start : Link
